# C assign array index to another

Tags: c, arrays

This probably has to do with C pointers cause it's an array problem.

Is it possible to assign an index of one array to another:

```
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    char b[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int num = 1;
    a[1 + num] = b[0];

    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%s", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I think the output should be what a would be. which i think would be [(null), (null), a]

**EDIT**

say I add an int array c to the code above:

```
int c[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

I am having trouble with storing values in the array a when I try to do something like this:

```
a[1 + c[0]] = b[0];
```

this ended up working as well...

it turns out this was not my issue thanks for the help though

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: `printf("%s", a[i]);` shouldn't that be `printf("%c", a[i]);`?

Comment: You'll want to use `%c` not `%s`.  Also, you should initialize array `a` otherwise you will be printing two uninitialized characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign like this. In this There may be a junk characters can available in
the array. So First you assign `0` to all.

```
char a[10]={0};
```

Then assign the value to index which you need.

After that while printing that use the `%c` in `printf`.

```
for(; i < 3; i++)
printf("%c", a[i]);
```

You can get the value which you assigned.

Comment: 0 and NULL are not the same thing. And NULL is not a valid character.

Comment: Even better :`for(; i < 3; i++)`